# promise cancellable bluebird

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird, cancellation

I have signup function in expressjs

```
app.post('/api/signup', function(req, res) {
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  if (!username || !password) {
    return res.status(400).end();
  }
  var promiseObject = userModel
    .findOne({username: username})
    .then(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        console.log(user);
        res.json({success: false, message: 'User or Email already exists !'});
        throw new promise.CancellationError()
      } else {
        var newUser = {username: username, password: bcrypt.hashSync(password)};
        return userModel.create(newUser)
      }
    })
    .cancellable()
    .catch(promise.CancellationError, function(e) {
      console.log(e.msg);
    })
    .then(function(user) {
      console.log('User created successfully');
      res.json({success: true});
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    })
});
```

When i call function from postman, this show error : Unhandled Rejection Error, can't not set header after they are sent

Comment: Which bluebird version do you use, exactly?

Comment: That's not the 3.0 syntax at all. Cancellation is broken in bluebird < 3 it took a while to get it right.

Comment: Apart from that I wonder if promise cancellation is even useful here in the first place, I really don't think so. Promise cancellation serves as a tool to interrupt the callback chain because something extraordinary happened, it is not for flow control. Everything you try to do can be done in the first `.then` callback.

Comment: I used Bluebird 3.1.1, if Cancellation is broken, so how do i cancel promise in promise chain ?

Comment: @Tomalak first i used promiseObject.cancel() but is not working, I want to cancel Promise chain when found user in database

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure you don't want to do that. As I said, *"Everything you try to do can be done in the first `.then` callback."*